# ScriptReferenceProfiler for ASP.Net 4 and 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In ASP.NET 3.5 (AJAX Control Toolkit), there is a neat tool called ScriptReferenceProfiler that can be used to find all scripts being used on a page, however, it doesn't work on ASP.Net 4.0 and up (tried recompiling the binaries to 4.5 with no luck) or any of the latest versions of the control toolkit.
Does anyone know of something similar? or a NEW link to the latest, working version (it's not on CodePlex)?

Basically, I want to combine the dozens of WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd javascripts into 1 single script, but I can't decode it without that tool.